# How can I print the customer name in the Orders view in Commerce 2?

Tags: commerce

I have a site where anonymous checkout is the default option. The problem with this is that the default order page simply shows "Anonymous" as the customer for every order in the list. I need to show the name of the actual customer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the order page is a View, you can modify the view to display what you want. However, it's not immediately obvious now to do this.

The steps I took were to add a relationship to the User entity, and then add another relationship to the User Profile (you need both relationships for this to work). From there, you can choose from three name fields for the Customer user profile type. I added the Given and Family name fields, hid them from display, and then rewrote the User column to output the first and last names followed by the user name, like this:

{{ address_given_name }} {{ address_family_name }} ({{ uid }})